# Highlight file contents fetched from GitHub

Tags: javascript, html, github, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

I cannot get syntax highlighting to work for code fetched from GitHub.

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => document.getElementById('code').textContent = data)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.7.0/build/styles/atom-one-dark-reasonable.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.7.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.7.0/languages/powershell.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>

<pre>
<code class="pwsh" id="code"> </code> 
</pre>
```

However, it's working with code in the same file.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.7.0/build/styles/atom-one-dark-reasonable.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.7.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.7.0/languages/powershell.min.js"></script>
<script>hljs.highlightAll();</script>

<pre><code class="pwsh">
    #PowerShell Hello World
   param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [String] $Name = "World"
)

"Hello $Name!"
 </code></pre>
```

How should one use the [code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code) and [pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tags together to highlight code fetched from GitHub?

Comment: The different is first example has `<code><pre>...</pre><'/code>` and second has `<pre><code>....</code></pre>`

Comment: `<pre id="code"><code class="pwsh"> </code> </pre>` didn't work with the GitHub fetched code either.

Comment: There are 2 more issues: make sure you're writing the text content into the `<code>` (not the pre) and make sure that `hljs.highlightAll();` is called after you loaded the code snippet into `<code>`

Comment: `hljs.highlightAll()` is called the same place in both examples. `<pre>
<code class="pwsh" id="code"> </code> 
</pre>` doesn't do the syntax highlighting either.

Comment: That’s because you’re inserting the code asynchronously _after_ highlight.js has been invoked and looked at the DOM. The DOM does not contain the GitHub code at runtime.

Comment: The theme background is loading fine. Calling `hljs.highlightAll()` after the `<pre>` tag doesn't help either.

Comment: You need to manually invoke highlighting for the element after fetching the data from GitHub. Use their `hljs.highlightElement()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why highlight.js doesn't work with your code, as I have pointed out in my comment, is that you are inserting the code asynchronously into your DOM *after* highlight.js has already parsed the DOM. As the code is only inserted after the page is loaded, highlight.js will not be able to detect it.

If you read through their documentation you'll discover that the plugin offers a `highlightElement()` method (scroll down the "Custom usage" section on their [documentation](https://highlightjs.org/usage/)), which allows you to manually highlight an element.

So the solution is simply invoking `hl's.highlightElement()` in the callback you use in your `.then()` chain:

```js
fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ayanmullick/test/master/AutomationAcc/test1.ps1")
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => {
    const codeElement = document.getElementById('code');
    codeElement.textContent = data;
    
    // Manually trigger code highlighting
    hljs.highlightElement(codeElement);
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.7.0/build/styles/atom-one-dark-reasonable.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highlightjs/cdn-release@11.7.0/build/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/11.7.0/languages/powershell.min.js"></script>
<pre>
  <code class="pwsh" id="code"> </code> 
</pre>
```